# WinJS Windows App - When I print a page, Is there a way to specify the printer?

Tags: windows, printing, windows-store-apps, winjs

To print my pages, I have something like that:

```
function onPrintTaskRequested(printEvent) {
    var printTask = printEvent.request.createPrintTask("Print Page", function (args) {

        // Get the print document source
        var src = MSApp.getHtmlPrintDocumentSource(document);
        args.setSource(src); 

        // Register the handler for print task completion event
        printTask.oncompleted = onPrintTaskCompleted;
    });
}
```

I would like specify the printer for the user does not need to choose the printer and print automatticly. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The user is always involved in the printing workflow in a straight Windows Store app. The app can [offer the print UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.printing.printmanager.showprintuiasync.aspx), and it can [suggest default general settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761453.aspx), but it can't pick a specific printer or print without the user's confirmation.

If you have a side-loaded app (in a kiosk, for example), then you can create a [Brokered Windows Runtime Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn630195.aspx) and use desktop printing API on the desktop side of the brokered component.